# How to log application loading time in Ionic Application? (In Ionic v3 and Ionic v4)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic3, ionic4

Few of my application users are complaining that they have to wait so long before the actual ionic application is loaded into their phone.

Is there any way in which I can measure the time for the actual application being loaded into my user mobile phone?

A working solution with Ionic Google Analytics would be preferred.

Answer (score -1):

if you have to build your ionic app in production mode.! then it will take 2-3 sec to start the app otherwise it takes time to load

try this command :

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

if you are working on ionic 3 version then you have to add lazy loading to improve performace!